# Display Email already exits

Tags: javascript, php

I need to Display "Email or phone number already exist" above to the "password-rules" div.

```
<form action="registrationProcess.php" method="post">
                    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
                    <div class="form-details">
                        <h3>Email </h3>
                        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
                        <h3>Name </h3>
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your Name">
                        <h3>Phone Number </h3>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number">
                        <h3>Password </h3>
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter a Strong Password">
                        <h3>re-enter Password </h3>
                        <input type="password" name="password_re" placeholder="re-enter the Password">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="password-rules">
                        <h6>At least 8 characters long but 10 or more is better.</h6>
                        <h6>A combination of uppercase letters, lowercase letters, numbers, and symbols.</h6>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Sign Up</button>
                </form>
```

**if email or phonenuber already stored in the database, "Email or phone number has already exist" should display above the "password-rules" div.**

```
if ($result->num_rows === 1) {
            echo "Email or phone number has already exist";
        }
```

```
$connection = new mysqli($server_name , $user_name , $dbpassword , $databaseName);
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM database_2.user WHERE `email` = "'.$email.'" OR `phone` = "'.$phone.'"';

        $result = $connection->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows === 1) {
            echo "Email or phone number has already exist";
        }else {
            if ($password === $password_re) {
                $query = "INSERT INTO database_2.user (`email`,`name`,`phone`,`password`)
                VALUES ('$email','$name','$phone','$password');";
    
                if($connection->query($query)){
                    header("Location: login.php");
                }else{  
                    echo "error";
                }
            }
        }
```

if i do it with "echo", my text will showing in another page. i think i need to do it with another method.

I have given display:none in css. After inputting the user details, if the email or phone number is stored in the database, the text "Email or phone number has already existed" will be displayed: block. But none of that worked.

Comment: You need to use AJAX if you don't want to submit a form and reload the page.